# How to find instance of an object in a collection within a collection in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to write an if statement that will find an instance of an object in a collection within another collection...

```
House 
has_many :occupants
Occupant 
has_many :shirts
belongs_to :house
Shirt
belongs_to :occupant
```

So if I want check if any of the occupants of house own a white shirt, I want to do something like this:

```
<% if @house.occuptants.shirts.where(:color => 'white') %>
```

However when I do that I get an error:

> undefined method `shirts' for #< Occupant::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

I believe because occupants is a collection in this case, but I'm not sure what the correct approach or syntax should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something simpler and that will help you later for different use cases is to add more to the relationships:

```
class House 
  has_many :occupants
  has_many :shirts, through: :occupants
end

class Occupant
  has_many :shirts
  belongs_to :house
  scope :females, -> { where(...) }   # This is homework for you: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes
end

class Shirt
  belongs_to :occupant
end
```

If you have a `House` instance:then you can check for occupants with white shirts as below:

```
<% if @house.shirts.where(color: 'white').exists? %>
```

and to check for female occupants with white color shirts, do:

```
<% if @house.occupants.females.select { |o| o.shirts.where(color: 'white').exists? } %>
```

Comment: The condition of the `if` will always be true. `where(color: 'white')` cannot return a falsy value, it will always return an active record result wrapping 0 or more records. You need to use `.exists?` to return a boolean true/false.

Comment: This is helpful, but I've also got a similar scenario where I need to check just for females with white shirts, ie. I need to validate an attribute on occupant as well.... in this case would the decorator approach be necessary?

Comment: @phauwn i have updated the answer to include your further query. For next times, please try to include all your queries in the question itself. This answer was perfect in itself.

Comment: Awesome @Jagdeep, don't worry, we are all here to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a presenter/decorator in this scenario.

Use [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) to decorate the house object like:

```rb
# /app/decorators/house_decorator.rb
class HouseDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def count_occupants_with_white_shirts
    object.occupants.joins(:shirts).where(shirts: { color: 'white' } ).count
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```rb
<% if @house.count_occupants_with_white_shirts > 0 %>
```

Hope that helps.

NOTE: If you don't want an additional dependency(Draper) you can also put that method inside you `House` model

Comment: This is not exactly decorating a model. It is more like adding a helper method to avoid calculations in the view. Should not go into the decorator. A good example of a decorator method is where you want to display a `Time`/`Date` object in pretty format.

Comment: Also, you will have to call the method on `@house.decorate`.